# node.js - difference websocket.io socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

What are the differences between node.js:

websocket.io
 and socket.io

which one is better for what?

```
https://github.com/LearnBoost/websocket.io

http://socket.io/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Websocket.io uses parts of the same engine socket.io uses. Socket.io has fallbacks so it doesn't just use websockets for sending information to the different browsers. This means greater compatibility with a greater number of users.

Both projects are maintained by the same group/person, but websocket.io has not been actively developed for about 9 months, plus there have been 4 releases of node.js since the last release. Socket.io however is being actively maintained and I would recommend using socket.io over the other.

The underlying technology of them both are the same - they both use something called engine.io (again, same guy). Websocket.io is just a cut down version and it should still work. If you want something extremely light without fallback support then go for that, but if you want something actively maintained then socket.io is your best bet.